# group elements like contact list in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of contacts(li) in my web page, I want to synchronize these contacts to be grouped like in a mobile.

How can we wrap all li containing same first letter of contact-name and generate a new li which will wrap all these li.  TIA.

**Html:-**

```
<ul id="contact-screen">
         <li class="myContacts_">               
             Almond  
         </li>
         <li class="myContacts_">
            Albert   
         </li>
           <li class="myContacts_">
            John   
         </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: how about you group contacts with first letter?
`<ul id="contact-screen"><li data-group="A"><ul class="contact-group"><li class="contact-item">Albert</li><li class="contact-item">Almond</li></ul></li><li data-group="B"></li><li data-group="C"></li> ... </ul>`

Comment: You should check all the contacts first letter and append into a specific list using JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a starter to order the contacts and rebuild the `ul` with group headers.

It will be up to you to style it.
;)

```js
var contactArray = [];

$(".myContacts_").each(function(){
  contactArray.push( $(this).text().trim() );
});
//console.log(contactArray);

// Sort the array (re-order it)
contactArray.sort();

// Clear the HTML list
$("#contact-screen").empty();

// Re-insert the contact with group headers based on the first letter.
var first_letter = "";
for(i=0;i<contactArray.length;i++){
  var this_first_letter = contactArray[i].substr(0,1).toUpperCase();
  
  // If this is a new first letter, add a group header
  if( this_first_letter != first_letter ){
    first_letter = this_first_letter;
    var group = $("<li class='group'>").text(first_letter);
    $("#contact-screen").append(group);
  }
  
  // Add the contact.
  var item = $("<li class='item'>").text(contactArray[i]);
  $("#contact-screen").append(item);
}
```

```css
#contact-screen li{
  list-style:none;
  width:15em;
  padding:4px;
  margin:0;
}
.group{
  border:1px solid black;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:bold;
  background-color:#ddd;
}
.item{
  border:1px solid blue;
  background-color:#aad;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="contact-screen">
  <li class="myContacts_">               
    Almond  
  </li>
  <li class="myContacts_">
    Albert   
  </li>
  <li class="myContacts_">
    Bob   
  </li>
  <li class="myContacts_">
    Bernard   
  </li>
  <li class="myContacts_">
    John   
  </li>
  <li class="myContacts_">
    Alice 
  </li>
  <li class="myContacts_">
    Christian  
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add this to any event that loads up the values:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="contact-screen">
         <li class="myContacts_">               
             Almond  
         </li>
         <li class="myContacts_">
            Albert   
         </li>
           <li class="myContacts_">
            John   
         </li>
</ul>

<ul id="contact-screen-grouped">
</ul>

<script>
var target_container = $('#contact-screen-grouped');
var contact_screen_grouped_values = {};
//generate grouped list as array
$('#contact-screen li').each(function (key, value) {
  var contact      = $(value).text().trim();
  var first_letter = contact.slice(0,1);

  //create a letter group if does not exist yet
  if (!contact_screen_grouped_values.hasOwnProperty(first_letter)) {
    contact_screen_grouped_values[first_letter] = [];
  }

  //add the contact value into the 'grouped' array
  contact_screen_grouped_values[first_letter].push(contact);
});

//write array as html lists
for (var letter in contact_screen_grouped_values) {
  if (contact_screen_grouped_values.hasOwnProperty(letter)) {
    var list_group_item = document.createElement("li");
    var list_group_ul = document.createElement("ul");
    list_group_item.append(list_group_ul);
    
    //sort the group alphabetically
    contact_screen_grouped_values[letter].sort();
    
    //create contact/list nodes and add them to the main list node
    $(contact_screen_grouped_values[letter]).each(function(index, value) {
      var list_contact = document.createElement("li");
      list_contact.append(value);
      list_group_ul.append(list_contact);
    });
  
    //put the elements into the DOM
    target_container.append(list_group_item);
  }
}
</script>
```

Explanation:
It loads the contents of your original list into an object where it creates a property for every first letter in your contacts. Then it adds an array of contacts under each 'letter' property. An object parsed in that way is then converted into DOM nodes and injected into the contact-screen-grouped list above. Hope that helps.